# make a fixed bottom navbar slide up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a fixed bottom navbar that will slide up when it is collapsed.  As far as I can tell i have it set up right, but when I click the collapse button nothing happens.

here is my html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom " role="navigation">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll animated infinite pulse" href="#page-top"><img src='assets/images/logo.png'></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#troposphere">TROPOSHPERE</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#stratosphere">STRATOSPHERE</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#mesosphere">MESOSPHERE</a>
                </li>
               <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#thermosphere">THERMOSPHERE</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#exosphere">EXOSPHERE</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

</nav>
```

I'd love some help if you can see what I've done wrong.

Comment: Have you attached the javascript bootstrap file as well?

Comment: Check **[this link](http://jsfiddle.net/mujwkusd/)** It's working fine!! You must have missed something!!

Comment: yet, I can copy and paste this code over what I have on the site and it still doesn't work.  I've screwed up something I'm sure, but I don't know where.  The links on the navbar do this odd thing where they jump down right before they collapse too